# Azure 'Web App on Linux' app service Application logging

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am currently using Azure 'Web app on Linux' that leverages docker containers to host a java app and a python app via private registry(Azure Container Registry) and I have yet to find a way to collect and analyze the application logs inside the container.

The goal is to analyze the application logs either by OMS, application insight or storage analytics. I understand that 'Web app on linux' is still in a preview state but there is no official documentation on what features are currently supported.

Does Azure 'Web app on Linux' via containers support exporting logs to blob storage or an application insight SDK for JAVA and Python yet? Plenty of documentation on how to configure it for asp.net and standard web app service but not much I can find out 'Web app on Linux containers'.

**What I have attempted so far with my JAVA application:** - Install JAVA SDK and log4js appender. I do see access/request logs in application insight but not my application logs inside the container.

What is the best solution or strategy to collect/view/analyze container application logs in 'Web App on Linux'?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Have you looked at Log Analytics Workspace?

Answer (score 1):

Application Insights does support Java and Python.

Here's a list of the supported platforms for Application Insights:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-platforms