# Application Insights not work in Web App for Azure Containers

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans

Folks,
Can you tell me how to enable application insights in a linux docker application on Azure?
Would I have to modify the service plan?

[image]

Comment: Just use the [SDK for the language of your choice](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home#officially-supported-sdks) and read the instrumentation key from App Settings (exposed as env var to your container). The latter is a manual step as well, you have to add in the key.

Comment: @evilSnobu I did this, but even configuring everything correctly application insights does not work !! I tested it with other languages too.

Comment: What does `Does not work` mean? You're not seeing telemetry coming in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure 'Web App on Linux' app service Application logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440681/azure-web-app-on-linux-app-service-application-logging)

Comment: @evilSnobu Telemetry is not coming!
If I create a non-docker application and set up telemetry, it works normally!

Comment: You absolutely sure you're picking up the right telemetry key in that container?